# Windows Phone 7 - Silverlight - Touch Input - TouchPoint.Size is always 1,1

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a small application for the WP7 using Silverlight, and it would be helpful for my application to be able to know the very basic dimensions of the touch fingerprint (height, width). After searching, I found and used the TouchPoint.Size property. However, this is always returning a value of 1 for both height and width.

Is this expected on the Windows Phone? Is it not supported? Is it a feature not supported by Silverlight? Is this information possible to grab from another API? Should I switch to XNA, does XNA support providing this information?

Answer (score 1):

SL doesn't tell you the size of the touch, and I don't know XNA well enough to know if it does either.

Answer (score 0):

did you try the WP7 Toolkit GestureService to get the position? This might work for you.

Comment: you are right, and yes, i did some testing and TouchPoint.Size is always 1. You would expect that this is supported as mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touchpoint.size(v=VS.95).aspx